# Retaining jQuery Slider Value on Reload

Tags: jquery, slider, salesforce, apex

I believe I've pulled everything correctly for this thing. Just trying to get my slider to remain where it last was on page load.

I'm passing the slider value to a hidden field, then using that field on page-reload, but while the save functionality is showing the correct value and saving to the DB, that same hidden value is not available on reload.

The slider is called "superSlider", its value is "sliderAmount", and the hidden field id is "hiddenMoney".

I'm calling it with startSlider to implement it with on-load methods.

Save functionality further down is what I'm using to store values in the DB and is not part of having this rerender with the page (at least I don't think so).

Help would be appreciated. :)

```
function startSlider(){
        $("#superSlider").slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 0,
            max: 1000,
            step: 100,
            value: ($('#hiddenMoney').val() || 0),
            change: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#sliderAmount" ).val(ui.value );
            }
        });
     alert('hidden value is: ' + $('#hiddenMoney').val());
     $("#sliderAmount").val($("#superSlider").slider("value"));
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".Save").click(function(){
              $('#hiddenMoney').val($("#superSlider").slider("value"));
              alert('hidden money value set to: ' + $('#hiddenMoney').val());
              var moneyAmt =  $( "#superSlider" ).slider( "value" );
              saveSlider(moneyAmt);
          });    
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into [`localStorage.setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You would retrieve the value with `localStorage.getItem()` inside of your document ready function and save it with `localStorage.setItem()` as part of your change function inside startSlider.

Keep in mind that the localStorage save and retrieve as a string data type. It would be good practice to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` when you retrieve the value to ensure you get a numeric value to keep the jQuery slider function happy. It will also save you many headaches if you perform certain math operations on the variable after it is retrieved.

Comment: Looked over this, and it looks good and easy to use, but my organization won't allow us to send any customer data to extraneous APIs. :/

Since we're dealing with sensitive financial data, even these small saved items are a no-go as far as sending to an API.